# MiKTeX Package Manager not installing subfigure package

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, subfloats

I am trying to install subfigure package in MiKTeX using:

```
mpm --verbose --install subfigure
```

But when I run this command in cmd in Windows 7, the crash notification comes up saying:

```
MiKTeX Package Manager (batch mode) has stopped working
```

How should I run the subfigure package then?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried the gui version of package manager?

Comment: @HarishKumar: How to open the gui version in Windows 7?

Comment: It should be available in `start → All Programs → MiKTeX 2.9 → Maintainance (Admin) →  Package Manager (Admin)`. Better choose (Admin).

Comment: @HarishKumar: When I try to install the packages subfig or subfigure through the GUI, the download screen comes up which is held forever.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Then it says MiKTeX package manager has stopped working and the GUI closes.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Everything used to work just fine as of yesterday. Both on my old installation and on a new installation of MikTex 2.9.4813. I'am thinking about a load issue on the remote server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very probably caused by a temporary server problem or a TeX distribution not properly updated. The questioner did not provide enough information.

Comment: It worked in Windows 10 with the same command.